# Can we use Angular (or similar frameworks) for development of Google Sheets Addon?

Tags: google-sheets-api, add-on

I've tried to search for an answer in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) but didn't find. Also, we'd like to publish our addon in the official Chrome Store. So I guess it's not forbidden to use a single app framework, right?